# Howto remote debug a vs2010 project on iis6?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6

I made a asp.net project in VS2010 with .net 4.0 everything works fine. but when I copied it to the server (IIS6 MS server 2003) it throws some exceptions and I don't know why, so I want to remote debug it, but I don't know how!

So how can I remote debug?

Comment: Can you paste the exception? There may be a simple answer.

Comment: its more easy to solve the error.

Comment: Does the server have the .NET 4 Framework installed to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger to your iis machine and then run msvsmon.exe for the platform you are running on then in VS just specify that you want to attach to that servers hostname and select the iis process, from memory its something like xxx_wp although I could be wrong.

You may also need to disable [just my code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) in Visual studio debugging settings.

Of course if VS is installed on the machine you have IIS on there is no need to copy the files simply run the debugger from the start menu shortcut for VS.

This [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IISRemoteDebugging.aspx) article will give you a better idea